# Wrong php date('t')

Tags: php, date

I have this script

```
echo 'giorni mese: '.date('t', $mese_start).' - mese start: '.$mese_start;
```

output is:

```
giorni mese: 31 - mese start: 11
```

But november doesn't have 30 days?

What am I missing?

---

Update:
right, thank you.

Comment: `$mese_start` is not a timestamp in November.

Comment: It all depends on what the value of `$mese_start` is

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `date()` is a timestamp, which is the number of seconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`. The value of `$mese_start` is `11`. So that timestamp is `1970-01-01 00:00:11 UTC`, and January has 31 days.

If you want to use `$mese_start` as a month number rather than a timestamp, you can use `mktime()` to create a timestamp from a particular date:

```
$ts = mktime(0, 0, 0, $mese_start);
echo 'giorni mese: '.date('t', $ts).' - mese start: '.$mese_start;
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) is interpreted as a Unix timestamp, not a month. You are passing "11" which equals some time on January 1st, 1970. And January has 31 days.

You could either construct a valid timestamp for November or use [`cal_days_in_month`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php):

```
echo cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 11, 2018); // 30
```